# Android MirroringFrameLayout always calls draw method which consumes cpu

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

In `MirroringFrameLayout`, the canvas passed to `draw` method is hardware accelerated but `bmpBackedCanvas` is not hardware accelerated.

Also it keep on calling `draw` method using preDrawListener, which forces redraw though nothing is changed on screen.

1.Is there any other way to invalidate the view when it changes instead of repeatedly posting `invalidte() ?`

2.Can `bmpBackedCanvas` be created as hardware accelerated (Layer type hardware)?

Answer (score 0):

1. The technique used there is to overcome some limitations of `WebView`, which does not use the normal view rendering pipeline (at least on 4.3 and older — I assume the same problem occurs in 4.4+ with the new Chromium-based `WebView`). I have filed [an enhancement request](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts/issues/6) to make that behavior more configurable. However, this is fairly low on my development priority list at the moment.
2. I am not aware that you can have a hardware-accelerated bitmap. If you can point me to a demonstration of how this works, I'd be happy to consider using it.

Comment: Acutally webview is not used in my case.